# List of default SNMP MIB tree values / OIDs?

Tags: network, snmp

I'm trying to find a resource that lists default SNMP mib values and object identifiers for various vendors / operating systems to use with `snmpwalk`. I have a list of MIB tree values for Microsoft Windows SNMP but can't find lists for other vendors. Is there a comprehensive source to use for this?